.env files and python package distribution
I am confused about something.
I have a python package that relies on hard coded values in a Config class.
Having done some reading, I want to move to a .env file and load the values from the .env file into the Config class. No issues here.
My confusion is around the topic of packaging/distribution. My package will be installed on machines and run locally by the user. Based on my approach above, I am confused on how to ensure the values from the .env file are included in the packaging phase.
I originally used a setup.py file and distutils but I am migrating to pyproject.toml and build for packaging.
I would appreciate any hints on how to to achieve this.
I have searched the setuptools docs and I am not seeing anything obvious. I do see a reference to an env in Entry Points require(env=None, installer=None) but am not sure if this is the same environment I am referring to.
I have also checked out the distutils docs and found distutils.util.check_environ() but again I can't see how to set the environment.
Edit: Just to clarify, if it is perfectly normal to include the .env file in packaging and distribution, then I am good to go. If it is not, then my question still stands I suppose

It sounds as though you are packaging an application with some configuration. Python packaging has very little to help with application packaging, you may want to consider a more appropriate packaging format such as rpm.

Thanks for your comment. I'll check it out. Yes you are right, I am packaging an application and I want to include environmental variables in the process without having to make multiple .env files and possibly fall in to the trap where someone else makes a mistake and includes the wrong .env file.

If your .env file contains secrets, then I would not package it. In my team we are in a similar situation. We build packages for analysts to use in their Notebooks. The packages connect to all kind of data sources, and therefore we use .env files for setting credentials and stuff. We simply wrote documentation for the users how to create their own .env files. That's it.
If you want to use the packages in a cloud application, then you can probably pass the environment variables in a build pipeline.
We use Pydantic, and with their dotenv support, you can either use .env files, or read from your environment variables directly (https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/pydantic_settings/#dotenv-env-support)

Thanks for the tip. I only came across Pydantic while trying to find solutions to this problem.

So you've imported setup from setuptools.
To include the .env file, add it to the package data and set inclusion of package data to True. This is done as below.
setup(
    ... # whatever other arguments you have already like the name, etc.
    package_data={'': ['.env']},
    include_package_data=True,
)

And let's say your package is called mypkg (I've not tested the below but this should work) you can do this in pyproject.toml instead as below. This assumes .env is in the root directory.
[tool.setuptools.package-data]
mypkg = [".env"]

If you need any other help or this isn't what you were quite looking for, drop a comment below.

Thanks for the quick reply! My understanding about using a .env file was to avoid having sensitive information included in files under source control. From your answer I am to assume that is perfectly fine and normal to include in the distribution of a package?

If you have sensitive information you should never include it in anything. Not distributions, not source control. Why do you want to distribute your .env file then? Is it just that you want to use those environment variables when packaging your project on your end or that you want those environment variables to be present on the client side?

I have a config class that is scattered throughout the application. Instead of hardcoding the values in the config class I want to load the values from an .env file when the application starts and inject them into the config instance. So while I have hidden the values away into an .env file I fall into the trap of what to do when packaging for distribution.

So do you simply want to omit the .env file from your distribution or do you want your users to have access to it?
